# how to merge our application with Facebook advertisements?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I saw in Facebook when you want to advertise your iOS Application you can set "Deep Link (optional)" which means that if someone is already install your app on his device and see this ad will have the button Open and the ad will not tax you. On Facebook developers pages has a link [GitHub](https://github.com/AppLinks/Samples) You can see in the description what it contains and my question is: How can be done in Swift and how to merge my application with Facebook ADS ?

Answer (score 0):

**By deep linking**.  you want to have option for launching/installing the app. [Mobile App Add Engagement](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads-engagement) link will be useful for you.

Further, Since the **call to action** method has multiple parameters such as install , rate , launch etc, you can follow the link mentioned above and understand the mobile app and its advertisement engagement. Please comment if you are facing any issues or it wasn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Swift question. You just need to follow [Facebook's instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads-engagement). Namely:

1. Figure out your deep link URL scheme ("fb" followed by your app ID, like `fb1234567://`)
2. [Add that URL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW10) to your `info.plist`
3. Enable Deep Linking in your [Facebook ad dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)
4. Optionally implement the `application(_:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:)` method if you want to do something specific when your app is launched by Facebook